# Summing array elements according to a flag vector

Tags: python

Consider I have this two arrays (one of them is a list, in fact)

`A = array([[0, 1, 2],[3, 4, 5],[6, 7, 8]])`

and

`flag = [[55, 55, 00], [55, 00, 33], [0, 33, 33]]`

I want to sum values in A using the corresponding values in flag as the key. The result should contain the sums of the corresponding groups for each of the values in A.

The resulting array should be

`B = [[4, 4, 12], [4, 12, 20], [12, 20, 20]]`

since, for example, the elements a11 (0), a12 (1) and a21 (3) have the same position of the key value (55) in the flag array. Anyone has an idea on how do it by using python?

PS: I have edited the question trying to make it more clear for other users who may have the same problem.

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: do you mean `A[flag == 55].sum()`?

Comment: could you explain a little better what kind of logic you're trying to implement... a flag 55 would sum(0+1+3) and a flag 33 would sum (5+7+8). I don't get your meaning

Comment: Apparently he's grouping values in `A` using corresponding values in `flag` as the key.  The result `B` will contain the sums of the corresponding groups for each of the values in `A`.

Comment: @mgilson Yes. This will help me a lot. I could not think anything as simple as that. With this I cam implement for all array elements. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @JeffMercado yes, exactly that. Sorry if a could not explain this more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible working solution:

```
from numpy import array
from collections import defaultdict

A = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
flag = [[55, 55, 00], [55, 00, 33], [0, 33, 33]]

keys = defaultdict(int)

for i, f in enumerate(flag):
    for j, v in enumerate(f):
        keys[v] += A[i][j]

B = [[keys[v] for j, v in enumerate(f)] for i, f in enumerate(flag)]
print(B)
```

Which gives the next output:

```
[[4, 4, 12], [4, 12, 20], [12, 20, 20]]
```

Comment: Thank you @BPL for you solution. It will be very helpful for the real case I am  working now. In my real case, I am working with 3D arrays. All elements of A are other arrays (a spectrum, in fact).